# How can I prevent Distimo of AppAnnie from tracking my app?

Tags: statistics, app-store, instrumentation, appannie

As many of you know, Distimo and App Annie offer downloads and revenue estimates from any app on mainstream appstores. Is there a way to instrument my code or manifest file in order to block those services from scanning my app? To clarify with an example: I'm looking for the equivalent of robot.txt but for apps.
Any help is welcomed.
(I've already asked how to remove my app from the listings and they gave me no answer)